# Wuapi.dll Search() not returning all updates

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, updates, wuapi

Testing the functions of wuapi.dll I noticed that some updates are not listed in the results (obviously because they are visible from the update manager).

Code used(c#):

```
        public ISearchResult CheckUpdates()
        {
          IUpdateSearcher uSearcher = uSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
          uSearcher.Online = true;
          ISearchResult uResult = uSearcher.Search("Type='Software' and IsInstalled=0");
          return uResult;
        }
```

Also tried all possible filters combination.

Update Manager Screenshot
[image: Update Manager Screenshot]

Anyone knows why?
Thanks.

Comment: Take out `Type='Software'` to also see updates

Comment: already done... no results.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
uSearcher.ServerSelection = ServerSelection.ssOthers;
uSearcher.ServiceID = "7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d";
```

And leave out the `Type='Software'` like Theo said.

Comment: With this 2 lines of code many more updates were found, but i still can't  find system updates.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the right filter that worked for me: `IsInstalled = 0 And DeploymentAction=*`